# How to run a curl command with headers using shell script

Tags: shell, curl, http-headers, access-token

I tried to run a shell script which contains a curl command with its required headers as below.

```
counter=1
H1='Content-Type: application/json'
H2='Accept: application/json'
H3='Authorization: Bearer a0a9bb26-bb7d-3645-9679-2cd72e2b4c57'
URL='http://localhost:8280/mbrnd_new/v1/post'

while [ $counter -le 10 ]

do

TEST="curl -X POST --header $H1 --header $H2 --header $H3 -d @s_100mb.xml $URL"
echo $TEST
RESPONSE=`$TEST`
echo $RESPONSE
sleep 5
done
echo "All done"
```

It gives an error as

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: a0a9bb26-bb7d-3645-9679-2cd72e2b4c57
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900902</ams:code><ams:message>Missing Credentials</ams:message><ams:description>Required OAuth credentials not provided. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"</ams:description></ams:fault>
```

The given access token and other header parameters are correct. It works fine when the 'curl' is called directly.

I tried different methods like using \" but nothing worked. I would be grateful if someone can provide a proper answer to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example will break, because substituting the individual header variables (`$H1`, ...) expands to strings containing spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command you want to execute is something like:

```
curl -X POST --header "$H1" --header "$H2" --header "$H3" -d @s_100mb.xml "$URL"
```

(I'll use `-H` instead of `--header` as it's shorter.)

The easiest way to do it is

```
response=$(curl -X POST -H "$H1" -H "$H2" -H "$H3" -d @s_100mb.xml "$URL")
```

The problem with your solution is that you're not delimiting the header values at all:

```
curl -X POST -H $H1
```

If the content of `H1` is `foo: bar`, then this will expand to

```
curl -X POST -H foo bar
```

and that will be interpreted as

```
curl -X POST -H (foo:) bar
```

(using `(` and `)` only to illustrate precedence, nothing like this works in shell), i.e. `bar` will be taken to be the first positional argument, which happens to be the hostname, leading to strange errors you see.

What you want is

```
curl -X POST -H (foo: bar)
```

which can be achieved by properly wrapping the expansions in quotes as illustrated above.

Also, you should [prefer $(cmd) to `cmd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated).

As a final piece of advice, if you're learning how to use the shell, it may be wise avoiding multiple expansions, i.e. don't store your command in a `CMD` variable to `$($CMD)` it later, as that leads to multiple expansions in multiple places (first where `CMD` was assigned, second when `CMD` was expanded in the `$(...)` sub-shell), making it hard to understand what the heck is going on.